# Can I use Chromium dev tools on mobile device?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chromium, webengine

I am mobile device web middleware developer, and I have to check some webapp's performance (not an Android, not an iOS device).

Those webapps (not a web service or web page. those are a kind of hybrid app) are very device dependent, so I can't use desktop Chromium dev tools.

Below is desktop Chromium performance dev tool.

I want to know "Loading time, Scripting time, Rendering time, Painting time".
How can I check those things on mobile device?

Command line interface, logs, anything is okay...

[image]

Comment: [Remote debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/)?

Comment: When posting here, please refrain from txtspk and sad/crying emoticons. Begging usually results in downvotes - remember you are addressing volunteers. If you can observe the usual case rules of English, that helps a lot also - Stack Overflow is not a chat room.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Remote Debugging](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/). The page actually runs on the mobile device, giving you an accurate view of mobile performance, but you inspect the performance from a laptop / desktop that’s connected to the device.